# What will client do if a Http Message Header contains 'Transfer-Encoding' but its value is not 'chunked'

Tags: http, http-headers

HTTP/1.1 [RFC 2616 4.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4.4) says `Content-Length` `MUST BE` ignored if the message contains `Transfer-Encoding`.And if it is `Transfer-Encoding:chunked`,the client can determin message body length by `chunk size` of `chunked`,but if it is not, how to determin the length of message body ?